# Using ImageMagick to get a fuzzy hash of an image

Tags: hash, imagemagick

I have a situation where I have many images, and I compare them using a specific fuzz factor (say 10%), looking for images that match. Works fine.

However, I sometimes have a situation where I want to compare all images to all other images (for e.g. 1000 images). Doing 5000+ ImageMagick compares is way too slow.

Hashing all the files and comparing the hashes 5000 times is lightning fast, but of course only works when the images are identical (no fuzz factor).

I'm wondering if there is some way to produce an ID or fingerprint - or maybe a range of IDs - where I could very quickly determine what images are close enough to each other, and then pay the ImageMagick compare cost only for those likely matches. Ideas or names of existing algorithms/approaches are very welcome.

Comment: You can compute one or more perceptual hashes similar to http:/www.phash.org with my phashes script using Imagemagick. The hashes are binary strings that can be stored in the image meta data or put into a database. You can then use my script, hamming, to compare the hashes. You can then set some threshold (like a fuzz) on the hamming score to decide if you want to do an Imagemagick compare. I also have a histogram comparison metric script. You could use the histogram metric score, which if within some threshold, then do the actual image. See http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few imaging hashing algorithms out there. pHash is the one that springs to the top of my mind. http://www.phash.org/. That one works with basic transformations that one might want to do on an image. If you want to be more sophisticated and roll your own, you can use a pre-trained image classifier like image net (https://www.learnopencv.com/keras-tutorial-using-pre-trained-imagenet-models/), lop off the final layer, and use the penultimate layer as a vector. For small # of images, you can easily do a nearest neighbor. If you have more, you cam use annoy (https://github.com/spotify/annoy) to make the nearest neighbor search a bit more efficient

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'm not sure whether any of these work out of the box, but now at least I have some vocabulary.